# Calculate $\int\int{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}dxdy$ the domain is $x^2+y^2 \le x$

Tags: integration

The question:

Calculate $\int\int{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}dxdy$

the domain is $x^2+y^2 \le x$

my solution:
[image]

the correct answer offered by my teacher :

[image]

I can't figure out why I am wrong.
I wonder which step I make mistakes ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\int_0^{\cos(\theta)}\sqrt{1-r^2}r dr=\frac13-\frac13(\sin^2x)^{\frac32}$ and not $\frac13-\frac13\sin^3x$.

Comment: I do not know what the differnce between the two?

Comment: @Math-fun Why they are not the same？ I don't know either

Comment: @satishramanathan: $a^3 = - (a^2)^{3/2}$ if $a < 0$.

Comment: @satishramanathan $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$.

Answer (score 0):

In the first step of your teacher's solution splitting the integral from $\frac{-\pi}{2} - \frac{\pi}{2}$ to $0 - \frac{\pi}{2}$ and at the same time dr becomes $dr^2$, the 2 that is generated from the first transformation cancels out with division of two from the later transformation of the derivative. Yours and the teacher's setting up of the integral are the same. The initial integrand is even  and your teacher has split the limits and added 2. Due to symmetry, you can change the limits to 0 to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and multiply by 2  **or** split the integral itself one with the limit $(\frac{-\pi}{2}) - 0$ and the other $0 - (\frac{\pi}{2})$